# how to select specific instances to be deleted

Tags: geometry-nodes

the seat objects are instanced on the ledge object. the length of the ledge object is controlled by the count on the mesh line node. how can i delete the first and last seat instance? i want this to work automatically even when i change the count number on the mesh line node. i have tried using index but that method requires me to change values in compare nodes for every count value i use in the mesh line node.

[image]

Comment: one way would be to use a curve line and use endselection and then curve to mesh. Or you use domain size and delete by index with 0 and domain size - 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly using points of the edges for instantiation, simply convert the selected edge to a curve first with `Mesh to Curve`, and then exclude the endpoints of this curve with `Endpoint Selection`:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>